# ng-options pass value from dictionary

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dictionary, select, ng-options

I have a dictionary, so in json

```
Object {1: "value1", 4: "value2" }
```

And I would like to pass selected value instead of key.

Now I code like this:

```
<select ng-model="myModel.myValue" ng-options="key as item for (key, value) in items" class="form-control">
<option value="">Choose</option>                                          </select>
```

Comment: try this `key as value for (key, value) in items`

Comment: The result is the same, still pass key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this `ng-options="value as value for (key, value) in items"`. it will assign value instead of key to ng-model

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
 $scope.items = {1: "value1", 4: "value2" };
  $scope.myModel = {}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<select ng-model="myModel.myValue" ng-options="value as value for (key, value) in items" class="form-control">
<option value="">Choose</option>                                          </select>
{{myModel.myValue}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ng-options="value as value for (key, value) in items
```

you were `ng-options="key as item for (key, value) in items"` here you were using the key as value which was the main reason for your answer not working

You need to use value of the key pair as value of the list and same value in the view panel.

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
 $scope.items = {1: "value1", 4: "value2" };
  $scope.myModel = {}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<select ng-model="myModel.myValue" ng-options="value as value for (key, value) in items"   ">                                     </select>
{{myModel.myValue}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try use `ng-repeat` in option instead of `ng-options`

```js
var app = angular.module('anApp', []);
app.controller('aCtrl', function($scope) { 
  $scope.items = {1: "value1", 4: "value2" };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="anApp" ng-controller="aCtrl">
  <select ng-model="myModel.myValue" class="form-control">
     <option ng-repeat="(key,value) in items" value="{{value}}">
       {{value}}
     </option>                                        
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: The result still is the same, it pass key

Answer (score 0):

See this:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
 $scope.items = {1: "value1", 4: "value2" };
  $scope.myModel = "value1";
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<select ng-model="myModel" ng-options="value for (key, value) in items"   ">                                     </select>
{{myModel.myValue}}
</div>
```